# Haskell, how to implement SQL like operations?

Tags: list, haskell, vector

I’m trying to do some SQL-like operations with Haskell, but I have no idea about what data structures to use. I have 3 different tables: customer, sales, and order. The schemas are below:

### Customer

- `custid` — integer (primary key)
- `name` — string

Example:

```
1|Samson Bowman
2|Zelda Graves
3|Noah Hensley
4|Noelle Haynes
5|Paloma Deleon
```

### Sales

- `orderid` — integer (primary key)
- `custid` — integer
- `date` — string

Example:

```
1|3|20/3/2014
2|4|25/4/2014
3|5|17/7/2014
4|9|5/1/2014
5|5|9/6/2014
```

### Order

- `orderid` — integer
- `item` — string

Example:

```
2|gum
4|sandals
3|pen
1|gum
2|pen
3|chips
1|pop
5|chips
```

What i want to do is to “merge” these three tables into a new table, and the schema of new table is:

```
Customername    Order#     Date       Items
Samson Bowman   17      20/3/2014 shoes, socks, milk
Samson Bowman   34      19/5/2014 gum, sandals, butter, pens, pencils
Paloma Deleon   41      6/1/2014  computer
…
```

So yeah, it is very SQL like. I know the SQL is very simple, but how can I implement this without SQL but instead using built-in data structure?

**TEXT PRINT ERROR**
When i run the function , it shows the following error:

```
Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
    Expected type: Customer -> String
      Actual type: Customer -> [String]
    In the first argument of `map', namely `formatCustomer'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `map formatCustomer result'
```

And i am thinking that the return type of condense is [Customer], but formatCustomer uses only Customer. is this the reason?

Comment: I once wrote this about using arrows for SQL-like list processing: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/haskell-cafe/vLgYxvVP2mM/7HbQjAtvmnQJ

Comment: But map is only working for two element tuple, here in saleDB, we have three element, how to deal with it? Thanks

Comment: I would recommend you go through the [persistent](http://yesodweb.com/book/persistent) chapter from the Yesod book.

Comment: It's not a SQL application. All the data are just stored in simple txt file. So I want to use simple data structure to collect them and make it easy:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your associations are one-to-many, and they don’t refer to eachother; it is strictly hierarchical. Customers have sales, sales have orders.  Given that, you probably wouldn’t store each bit of information separately, but hierarchically as it truly is.  I might put it into data types like this:

```
data Customer = Customer { customerName :: String
                         , sales        :: [Sale]
                         } deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

data Sale = Sale { saleDate  :: Day
                 , soldItems :: [String]
                 } deriving (Eq, Read, Show)
```

This will probably be very easy to manipulate from within Haskell, and, as a bonus, it’s very easy to turn into the table you wanted to end up with, simply because it’s so close to that in the first place.

---

But maybe I’ve misinterpreted your question and you’re not just asking for the best data structure to hold it, but how to convert from your flat data structure into this sort of structure.  Fortunately, that’s easy enough.  Since everything is keyed, I’d construct a [`Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map.html#t:Map) and start [`unionWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map.html#v:unionWith)ing things in, or even better, do both at once with [`fromListWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map.html#v:fromListWith).  To put that more concretely, say you have these data structures:

```
data DBCustomer = DBCustomer { dbCustomerName :: String
                             , dbCustomerID   :: Int
                             } deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

data DBSale = DBSale { saleOrderID    :: Int
                     , saleCustomerID :: Int
                     , dbSaleDate     :: Day
                     } deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

data DBOrder = DBOrder { dbOrderID   :: Int
                       , dbOrderItem :: String
                       } deriving (Eq, Read, Show)
```

If I wanted a function with the type `[DBSale] -> [DBOrder] -> [Sale]`, I could write it easily enough:

```
condense :: [DBSale] -> [DBOrder] -> [Sale]
condense dbSales dbOrders = flip map dbSales $ \dbSale ->
    Sale (dbSaleDate dbSale)
       $ fromMaybe [] (Map.lookup (saleOrderID dbSale) ordersByID) where
  ordersByID = Map.fromListWith (++) . flip map dbOrders
             $ \dbOrder -> (dbOrderID dbOrder, [dbOrderItem dbOrder])
```

Here I’m discarding the customer ID since there’s no slot in `Sale` for that, but you could certainly throw in another `Map` and get whole `Customer` objects out:

```
condense :: [DBCustomer] -> [DBSale] -> [DBOrder] -> [Customer]
condense dbCustomers dbSales dbOrders = flip map dbCustomers $ \dbCustomer ->
    Customer (dbCustomerName dbCustomer)
           $ lookupDef [] (dbCustomerID dbCustomer) salesByCustomerID where
  lookupDef :: (Ord k) => a -> k -> Map.Map k a -> a
  lookupDef def = (fromMaybe def .) . Map.lookup
  salesByCustomerID = Map.fromListWith (++) . flip map dbSales
                    $ \dbSale -> (saleCustomerID dbSale,
                                  [ Sale (dbSaleDate dbSale)
                                  $ lookupDef [] (saleOrderID dbSale)
                                              ordersByID])
  ordersByID = Map.fromListWith (++) . flip map dbOrders
             $ \dbOrder -> (dbOrderID dbOrder, [dbOrderItem dbOrder])
```

---

## Printing

This should be reasonably easy.  We’ll use [`Text.Printf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Text-Printf.html) since it makes putting things in columns easier.  On the whole, each row in the result is a `Sale`.  First, we can try formatting a single row:

```
formatSale :: Customer -> Sale -> String
formatSale customer sale = printf "%-16s%-8d%-10s%s"
                                  (customerName customer)
                                  (orderID sale)
                                  (show $ saleDate sale)
                                  (intercalate "," $ soldItems sale)
```

(Actually, we discarded the order ID; if you want to preserve that in your output, you’ll have to add that into the `Sale` data structure.)  Then to get a list of lines for each customer is easy:

```
formatCustomer :: Customer -> [String]
formatCustomer customer = map (formatSale customer) $ sales customer
```

And then to do it for all customers and print it out, if `customers` was the output of `condense`:

```
putStr . unlines $ concatMap formatCustomer customers
```

Comment: Thanks! At first I didn't notice that I can create own data but just think about doing it with list of tuple . It may work for only two element but my sales db had three. Can u give more details? Cuz I wanna see how to connect three data structure

Comment: @user3889372: I edited my answer to show how joining all three might look. I notice in the comments on your question you say you’re doing this for data persistence—if you just want to store stuff quickly without any need to be compatible with any *particular* format, you can use `read` and `show` if your data types derive `Read` and `Show`. Then your files will look like Haskell literals.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code but some little mistake happened. It says "Not in scope:' sale'", at this place: $ \dbSale -> (saleCustomerID sale,
                                  [ Sale (dbSaleDate dbSale)
                                  $ lookupDef [] (saleOrderID dbSale)
                                              ordersByID]) . I will try to fix it before your reply.

Comment: And by the way, i search for the "flip map" and Map.Map on Google, but only found that Map.map. What is the difference between Map and map here? I am newer for haskell, very appreciate your help!

Comment: @user3889372: Sorry about the `sale`—that was supposed to be `dbSale`.  When searching for Haskell documentation, you’ll generally find [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) better than Google.  [`Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#t:Map) from `Data.Map` is a data structure that “maps” keys to values.  [`map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) is a function that transforms each element of a list.  [`flip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) swaps the arguments of a function.

Comment: @user3889372: To elaborate on the `flip map` bit, you can translate `map f l` to `flip map l f`.  It’s generally more useful to have the `f` first for currying, but here the `f` expression is more complex than `l`, so I flipped it around so I can use `$` and avoid a bunch of parentheses.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works for me now! i am happy. I have tried to read these three files into string, and then insert each line into the according record, and finally make a list of record. The last task is to format the result,[Customer]. I just want to print this like the schema i put in the question so that its more readable, any idea ? Thanks!

Comment: @user3889372: I edited my answer to show how you might format the output.  Note that you’ll have to edit the data structure to include the order ID if you want that in your output; we’re currently discarding it.

Comment: ah,yes, i want to make orderID in the Sale, but just adding it makes some error, should i modify the condense function also? I try to modify it but have not made it yet. But i will try this format printing now, thanks!

Comment: @user3889372: Yes, you’ll have to modify `condense` to put the order ID into `Sale`.

Comment: I added "orderID" into Sale record , and in condense function, i add orderID into Sale(orderID dbSaleDate dbSale) , but is not working? Where should i modify for condense? I m a little confused about those characters

Comment: @user3889372: I will assume you’ve added `orderID` to the beginning of `Sale`. To construct a `Sale`, we give it three parameters: the order ID, the sale date, and the sold items.  In that piece of code we’re currently fetching the sale date and constructing the list of sold items.  It’s not sufficient to just stick in an `orderID` to some existing expression; you need to insert `(saleOrderID dbSale)` as the first argument to `Sale`.

Comment: I am confused..LOL, should i add orderID or saleOrderID into Sale, where should i change for Condense function? Thanks, and i met some error when text printing, i put the error on the question part.

Comment: @user3889372: I fixed the type error, but I think I’m going to leave the specifics of how to change the data structure and `condense` to you.

Comment: OMG, i made it!! I know why i m wrong because i didnt know that saleOrderID is from dbSale which is the result of lambda operation?Right?HAA, but thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

I have some similar problems and the best I found to do SQL *Join* operations is to use the `align` function from the [these](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these) package, combined with `Map` (where the key is on what you want to join).

The result of `align` will give you a map or list of `These a b` which is either an `a`, a `b` or both. That's pretty neat.